# Setup PHPUnit to log code coverage

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

I've been searching up how to set up `phpunit` or `phpunit.xml` to log code coverage reports, but I keep finding [docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html) like *How to include files*, *How to ignore code blocks*, and such, but nothing on setting it up. Can I get some instruction on setting code coverage up with phpunit?

Answer (score 0):

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html points you to https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html for a list of commandline switches that control code coverage functionality and to https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.logging for the relevant configuration settings.

https://thephp.cc/dates/2015/05/php-tek/code-coverage-covered-in-depth is a presentation on code coverage that has plenty of examples.